# Making if -statement in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

**How can you say the following in jQuery?**

> If If textarea AND input.title are NOT empty, then put input.button ON.

**My attempt in pseudo-code**

```
if ( $(textarea).not.empty() AND $(input.title).not.empty() ) {
   $('.ask_question').attr('enabled, 'enabled'); 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What would jQuery-jesus do?

```
$('textarea').is(":contains('')")
```

or

```
$('input.title').is(":empty")
```

I suppose ;)

Comment: This solution is actually better than mine :)

Comment: Does that work like an IF statement? If so, it seems less readable.

Comment: jQuery.is() returns a boolean and I'd say that it's very readable :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( $("textarea:empty").length == 0 && $("input.title:empty").length == 0 ) {
   $('.ask_question').attr('enabled', 'enabled'); 
}
```

The <strike>method</strike> property [length](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/length) of jQuery returns the number of elements which were selected. [:empty](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/empty) is a selector for jQuery to select elements which have no child or no text.

So,

```
if (number of empty textarea is 0) AND (number of empty input with the class title is 0) then
   enable somthing!
```

Comment: `length` is a property, not a method.

Comment: Firebug gives me the following error for your code: `$("textarea:empty").length is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("#myTextArea").val().length != 0 && $("#myTextBox").val().length != 0) {
   $('.ask_question').removeAttr("disabled"); 
}
```

You can use "textarea" and "input[class='title']", but it is possible for these to return multiple results.

Comment: Your code seems to need this `.length` after the second `.val()`. However, I have not yet managed to get your code to work with or without the addition.

Comment: Well spotted, it does need .length after val(). Do you get an error or unexpected results?

Answer (score 0):

Not too far off.

```
if ( $("textarea").val().length && $("input.title").val().length ) {
  $('.ask_question').removeAttr('disabled'); 
}
```

Comment: @andy, i totally agree. having `0 == false` is a very hand shortcut, which cuts a lot of useless verbosity from your code.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ( $("textarea").val() != "" && $("input.title").val() != "" ) {
   $('.ask_question').attr('enabled', 'enabled'); 
}
```

Comment: You're missing a quote there: should be `attr('enabled', 'enabled')`.

Comment: $(textarea).value() - value() isn't a jQuery method - it's val(). Also the selectors should be enclosed in quotes and ideally only return a single item.